# NodeJS - returning undefined issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Trying to create a blog website where users can comment on posts. I was able to create different blog posts so now I am trying to implement the comment feature. In my routes/admin/comments.js file I was able to create a comments array and append each comment into the array. I am using EJS to try to display the comments which should be <%=comments%> but I am getting an error that says 'comments is not defined' even though I have defined it in:

```
  Comment.find({})
    .then(comments =>{
      console.log(comments)
      res.render('home/post', {comments})
    })
})
```

What am i doing wrong? I am following the same method I did with creating posts.

models/Post.js Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
  title:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  body:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  comments:[{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'comments'
  }]
},{usePushEach:true})

module.exports = mongoose.model('posts', PostSchema);
```

models/Comment.js Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  username:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  body:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('comments', CommentSchema)
```

routes/admin/comments.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Post = require('../../models/Post');
const Comment = require('../../models/Comment');

router.get('/', (req,res) =>{
  Comment.find({})
    .then(comments =>{
      console.log(comments)
      res.render('home/post', {comments})
    })
})

//Finds the comments and makes it available as object
router.post('/', (req,res) =>{
  Post.findOne({_id: req.body.id})
    .then(post=>{
      console.log(post)
      const newComment = new Comment({
        username: req.body.username,
        body: req.body.body,
      });
      post.comments.push(newComment);
      post.save()
        .then(savedPost =>{
          newComment.save()
            .then(savedComment =>{
              res.redirect('/')
            })
        })
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: are you sure you have some records in your database?

Comment: @EugenSunic Yes. I am looking at my MongoDB right now and there are two collections,  'comments' and 'posts'. Within the 'posts' collection, it has an array called 'comments'  and it has the objectID's of the comments